# Run application as 32 bit in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to develop a small application which must interact with a very old version of access and pull the data out. We have a solution already in powershell but we want to move away from powershell and get it in C#

I think I have code that should work theoretically, but there's one setback, it must be run in 32-bit mode due to the age of the access version I'm working with. When I run my app, there are no exceptions, I simply get a message in my debug console that says:

`The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

The powershell has a requirement that it must be run in 32-bit powershell and after researching the above message I believe my application must also be run in 32-bit mode. I have also settled on using OLEDB to access the file, just as the powershell does, further adding to my assumption

I primarily use VSCode to develop here, but I am not above installing regular Visual Studio if necessary

I installed the 32-bit VSCode and ran my application there but I got the same message

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't use VS Code for C#, but I believe this is the compiler option you want: [-platform (C# Compiler Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/platform-compiler-option)

Comment: Is there a similar way for .net core?